# RabbitMQ - consume messages from a classic queue to a MQTT connection

Tags: python, rabbitmq, mqtt

I'm trying to consume messages from a queue in RabbitMQ which is already set up and has some messages. I am testing the MQTT subscriptor with a connection with the paho library:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from paho.mqtt.enums import CallbackAPIVersion

def on_connect(client, userdata, connect_flags, reason_code, properties):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(reason_code))
    client.subscribe("sv/iqf/area/0/#")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Received message: "+msg.payload.decode())

client = mqtt.Client(callback_api_version=CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION2)  # Provide callback_api_version argument
client.username_pw_set("user", "password")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("IP", 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

However, I can't make the new subscription queue (MQTT connection) consume the classic queue messages as described in the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2023/03/21/native-mqtt):

[image: Desired connection]

My current set up for the classic queue to get the messages from is the following:

[image: Queue with messages to consume from]

And the MQTT subscription queue is set as:

[image: Queue to send the messages to]

If the connection is up and the messages are sent to the specified routing key then both queues will get the messages, but my goal is to get them to the first queue in case the subscriber connection is unstable and can consume them whenever it connects.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to consume messages from a queue in RabbitMQ which is already set up and has some messages.

It's not possible to consume via MQTT from a queue created outside the MQTT plugin.

Comment: The queue was created within RabbitMQ with the MQTT plugin installed, and the MQTT connection queue was created by the plugin automatically once the connection was set

Comment: could you please point me somewhere I can see how to create a queue within the MQTT plugin please? Can't find it in the docs.